# WebGL Unavailable after chrome updated

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, gpu, citrix

Currently I use cloud desktop with ***Citrix System without GPU***. The webGL works well with Chrome48.

But the WebGL is unavailable now after the chrome updated to 58.0.3029.110.

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

It(chrome://gpu/) said:
Graphics Feature Status

- Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable

Flash:
   Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable

Flash Stage3D:
   Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable

Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable

***WebGL: Unavailable WebGL2: Unavailable***

Problems Detected:

- GPU process was unable to boot: All GPU features are blacklisted.

Disabled Features: all

Drivers older than 2009-01 on Windows are
   possibly unreliable: 72979, 89802, 315205 Disabled Features: all

VPx
   decoding isn't supported before Windows 10 anniversary update.:
   616318 Disabled Features: accelerated_vpx_decode GPU rasterization
   should only be enabled on NVIDIA and Intel DX11+, and AMD RX-R2 GPUs
   for now.: 643850 Disabled Features: gpu_rasterization

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it. I Just went to settings, advanced settings and enabled hardware acceleration(at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. But it doesn't work. The main issue is the PC hasn't GPU.

Comment: After the chrome updated to 60, it works again. It seems the problem with chrome.